# How to read file that lots of different name with loop? and I How to wirte in json file?

Tags: python

example : S1-1.jpg, S1-2.jpg, S1-3.jpg in static directory

Now I wrote like this but it looks so messy

```
image = open('./static/S1-1.jpg', 'rb') #open binary file in read mode
            image_read = image.read()
            image_64_encode = base64.encodestring(image_read)
image.close()

image = open('./static/S1-2.jpg', 'rb') #open binary file in read mode
            image_read = image.read()
            image_64_encode = base64.encodestring(image_read)
image.close()

image = open('./static/S1-3.jpg', 'rb') #open binary file in read mode
            image_read = image.read()
            image_64_encode = base64.encodestring(image_read)
image.close()
```

and I want to write to json file's "URL"

json file's example

```
{ "intents": [ {
    "tag": "S1-1",
    "patterns": ["Where is S1-1", "S1-1", "Find S1-1","How to go to S1-1","Where S1-1"],
    "responses": ["S1-1 : Blue is Library, Red is destination."],
    "URL":[""]
    } ] }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
files = ["S1-1", "S1-2", "S2-55" ]                   # a list of all the file names you want to use
for cur in files:
    image = open(f'./static/{cur}.jpg', 'rb') #open binary file in read mode
    image_read = image.read()
    image_64_encode = base64.encodestring(image_read)
    image.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot But There's a lot of names like S1-1~1-7, S2-1, N4-1 etc. In this case how it should be? sorry for details

Comment: Edited the answer. Check it now. If you find the answer helpful, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

1. Create a list of file names. This requires you to enter the file names manually.

```
    filenames = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
```

2. Create a variable to store the file contents. This variable will store the text of the file for each iteration. "File_in" is an empty list that can store the contents of each file on each iteration.

```
    file_in = list()
```

3. Use a "for" loop to cycle through each file name in the file name list. This will ensure each file opens and has a reference variable in the "file_in" list:

```
    x = 0 for item in filenames:
        file_in[x] = open(item, 'r')  
        x += 1
```